# Syntax error in an array with values and keys

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this line.
it says `uncaught syntax error` in the console.

```
 var aqar= new Array(1:'1_2',2:'5_1',3:'3_3');
```

Comment: Please read a JavaScript tutorial to learn the basic syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide. Why did you think this line would be correct in the first place?

Comment: I came from PHP background. I thought it's possible to have custom keys in the javaScript array.

Comment: Not in an array.  An array is simply a 'list'/enumeration of objects, it is not a key-value store.  That is an object, or a map.

Comment: @GrailsGuy: Actually, JavaScript arrays **are** generalized key/value stores. Their "array-ness" is a myth ([link](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)), they're just objects with a couple of extra features. That doesn't mean you should use them when you don't need the extra array-like features, of course. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really trying to create an array, normally JavaScript arrays are `0`-based, not `1`-based, and that's now how you initialize them.

Here's a zero-based array

```
var aqar = ['1_2', '5_1', '3_3'];
```

Or you may prefer to use a non-array object:

```
var aqar = {
    1: '1_2',
    2: '5_1',
    3: '3_3'
};
```

...but then you won't have all the great `Array` stuff.

If you really want to, you can create a JavaScript array that has no element at position `0` like this:

```
var aqar = [];
aqar[1] = '1_2';
aqar[2] = '5_1';
aqar[3] = '3_3';
```

That creates a *sparse* array (an array with holes in it). It has no element `0`. (As opposed to having an element `0` with the value `null`, which is what another answer here does.) But unless you have a very good reason, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing arrays and objects in JavaScript.

Arrays have no keys when you define them:

```
var aqar = new Array('1_2', '5_1', '3_3');  // These lines
                                            // do the same
var aqar = ['1_2', '5_1', '3_3'];           // things
```

Otherwise, you need to define an object:

```
var aqar = { 1 : '1_2', 2 : '5_1', 3 : '3_3' };
```

Comment: `var aqar = ['1_2', '5_1', '3_3'];` is much better than the `new Array` form. Otherwise, +1

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed, thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd way to construct an array. Try:

```
var aqar = ['1_2','5_1','3_3'];
aquar[0]; //1_2
aquar[1]; //5_1
aquar[2]; //3_3
```

or if you intended to use objects:

```
var aquar = {
    "1": "1_2",
    "2": "5_1",
    "3": "3_3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid array syntax, and never has been.

If you want to make your array one-based, use `null` as the first element. Also, don't use `new Array()` when you don't need to:

```
var aqar = [null,'1_2','5_1','3_3];
```

Answer (score 0):

you mix arrays with hash.
array:

```
var a = ['1_2','5_1','3_3']; //a[0] = '1_2'
```

hash:

```
var a = {1:'1_2',2:'5_1',3:'3_3'}; //a[1] = '1_2'
```